# How to check if there is an entry that exists in an array/list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

My code is assigning values to names out of a list.  I need to know how to retrieve or set a default value if there is not an entry in my list to assign to one of the names. My code so far:

```
array =[[a],[b],[c],[d]]
no1 = array[0]
no2 =array[1]
no3 =array[2]
no4 =array[3]
# if array[4] exists:
    no5 = array[4]
else
    no5 = 0
```

I tried-

```
try:
    array[4]
except ValueError:
    no5 = 0
```

but it came up as array[4] out of range.

Just to clarify, as my code writing isn't spectacular, basically I am being given three different inputs for a program which should read these inputs and then write the  outputs to a file.
The problem is that all of the inputs have varying array lengths. So what I'm trying to do is somehow get the program to check if there is an entry for (say) array[4] and if that entry doesn't exist, create entry array[4] and make it equal to zero.

Comment: a little confused about what you're trying to do, please try reformatting your code to make it easier to read! I can say that the 'out of range' error is due to you called the 5th element (index of 4) of the list when there are only 4 elements

Comment: The point of having items in a list is that you don't have to name them.  This is an important level of indirection in programming.

Comment: I think what you really want is a dictionary.  Dictionaries have methods specifically for missing items.  Also, dictionaries allow you to associate names with items.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?  If so please accept one.

Answer (score 1):

That you went to `try` and / `except` is good.  If you got an `IndexError` then you're really close, you just caught the wrong type of error in your `except`.  This would've worked:

```
try:
    no5 = array[4]
except IndexError:
    no5 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be catching `IndexError` (the actual error being raised by `array[4]`) rather than `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `try` you can also check the length of the array

```
def: elem_exists(arr, idx):
   return 0 <= ldx < len(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to catch the wrong exception type

```
try:
    no5 = array[4]
except IndexError:
    no5 = 0
```

A nifty one-line solution for this is to use [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
import itertools
(no1,no2,no3,no4,no5),_ = zip(*itertools.izip_longest(array[:5],range(5),fillvalue=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like the following?

```
if len(array) > 4:
    no5 = array[4]
else:
    no5 = 0
```